# Why do "dotnet new angular" and "dotnet new webapi" create different controllers?

Tags: .net-core

Why do these two .NET Core commands create different signatures for Web API controllers?

```
dotnet new angular
```

will create

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleDataController : Controller
```

while `dotnet new webapi`

will create

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
```

In both cases it creates web API. However, in `dotnet new webapi` it applies the `ApiController` attribute and derives from ControllerBase, while in `dotnet new angular` there isn't any `ApiController` attribute and it derives from `Controller`.

This is for the same version of .NET Core 2.1. Why?

Comment: Not all templates have been updated to the latest version, so in this case, the WebApi template is the newest, that's why you see a different ControllerBase and a ApiController attribute, the angular template hasn't been updated yet, it still uses Angular 5 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

**dotnet new webapi** produces the controller that you'll want to mimic. Using the ApiController attribute and ControllerBase is the latest/recommended approach.